# Changing the color of the boxes and their margin using forest

Tags: forest

I have a decision tree made from the code below. Yet, so far I have not been able to get rid off the shadowy properties of the boxes. I would like the boxes around the names to have a black margin and a simple white background. Can you give me a hint how to do this?

Best,
Julian

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge={thick, draw=black},
    font=\sffamily\bfseries,
    text=black,
    top color=white!90!black,
    bottom color=white!60!black,
    text width=35mm,
    text centered,
    minimum height=10mm,
    rounded corners = 3,
    grow=right,right,
    l sep'=20mm,
    s sep'=10mm,
  },
  forked edges,
  [Food\\
    [Bread\\Oats]
    [Dairy goods\\
    [Cream]
    [Yoghurt]
    [Milk]
    [Butter]
    [Cheese]
    ]
    [Potatoes\\Pasta\\Rice]
    [Fruits]
    [Vegetables]
    [Meat\\
    [Poultry]
    [Pork]
    [Beef]
  ]]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead edit your question to include the fragment into a compilable document that people can play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. The defined style (`block`) deals with the properties of the boxes.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\tikzset{
    block/.style={draw, 
    anchor=east,    
    font=\sffamily\bfseries,
    fill=white, % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    text width=35mm, 
    text=black,
    text centered, 
    rounded corners=3pt,
    minimum height=10mm},   
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge={thick, draw=black},
    block, % style <<<<<<<<<<   
    grow=0,
    l sep+=10mm,
    s sep+=10mm,
},
forked edges,
    [Food\\
    [Bread\\Oats]
    [Dairy goods\\
    [Cream]
    [Yoghurt]
    [Milk]
    [Butter]
    [Cheese]
    ]
    [Potatoes\\Pasta\\Rice]
    [Fruits]
    [Vegetables]
    [Meat\\
    [Poultry]
    [Pork]
    [Beef]
    ]]
\end{forest}    
    
\end{document}
```

If you are planning to create multiple trees, you may want to define a default style like

```
\forestset{
    default preamble={
      for tree={
        edge={thick, draw=black},
        block, % style <<<<<<<<<<   
        grow=0,
        l sep+=10mm,
        s sep+=10mm,
    },
        forked edges,
        }}
```